# Can't reinitiate UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I've three views: login view, register view and main view "tabController" with 4 tabs each tab contains UINavigationController

first, the user login or register and present the main view "tabController" , from the 4th tab, he can logout, when logout, present the login view, after login, present the "tabController" AGAIN, what happens is that the old data is there from the previous login!!!
I want to reinitialize the tabController!!!!

the tabController is created in the MainWindow, and get IBOutlet in the AppDelegate

how to do this?!

Comment: Rather than reinitiating the Tabbar why don't you set the value of the components in ViewWillAppear, with checking some condition before and after logout.

Comment: I may do, but it would be mush easier to reinitialize it